504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT deploying to vercel
I'm trying to upload my project to vercel but every time I try it keeps saying the error. I'm using mongo dB with azure which has the free database in south Asia. so I used that and made the storage account in Asia.in the logs im getting:
MAY 09 13:15:33.90 GET---linkedin-clone-v2-rkp81em3s-my-team-7b85769e.vercel.app/---- Connecting to MongoDB ----
MAY 09 13:15:44.08 GET
linkedin-clone-v2-rkp81em3s-my-team-7b85769e.vercel.app
/
Task timed out after 15.02 seconds
I'm guessing the time out was for mongo db but not sure
i have followed along with Sonny Sanga's youtube tutorial exactly but mine wont deploy :/
Ive tried a few things:
Changed the vercel function region to southeast Asia.
created a new db and storage.
started a trial for vercel pro to increase the Serverless Function Execution Timeout.
i was hoping these things would work but i still get the same error.
